# 1次元配列からCSV出力が意図した結果にならない

Tags: python, python3

CSVモジュールを使って、以下2つのコード（sample-01／02.py）でリストをCSVファイルへ書き出しを行っているのですが、意図した結果となりません。
以下の違いの説明をいただけたらと思います。

```
# 意図した結果
aaa
bbb
```

```py
# sample-01.py

import csv
list_a = ['aaa', 'bbb']

with open('sample-01.csv', 'w', newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(list_a)
```

```
#sample-01.csv

a,a,a
b,b,b
```

```py
# sample-02.py

import csv

list_a = ['aaa', 'bbb']
with open('sample-02.csv', 'w', newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for li in list_a:
            writer.writerow(li)
```

```
# sample-02.csv

a,a,a
b,b,b
```

Comment: `writer.writerows([list_a])` として下さい。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。なぜ、`writer.writerows([list_a])`とするのでしょう？

Comment: 本来, カンマ区切りの項目1行分には .`writerow(row)` 使います (rowにはリスト的なものを指定)。複数行で `writerows()` 使うなら「リストのリスト」的な rowsを指定します。(質問のデータでは, それぞれ次元がひとつずつ足りない)

Comment: `list_a` をさらにリスト化することで、`list_a` 全体を1行として書き込む様になります。`list_a` をそのまま渡すと、'aaa' を1行目に、'bbb' を2行目に書き込むわけですが、その際に文字列は(sequence 型でもあるので)1文字ごとに分解されてしまうことになります。(`aaa` => `a,a,a`, `bbb` => `b,b,b`)

Comment: 読み間違えていました、`writer.writerows([i] for i in list_a)` として下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下は, 横に並べたものと, 縦に並べたものです

```py
import csv
import io

list_a = ['aaa', 'bbb']
with io.StringIO() as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerow(list_a)   # list_a は一行分のカラム

    for row in list_a:
        writer.writerow([row])   # 縦並び (1行分は 1項目のリストを指定)

    res = fp.getvalue()

print(res)
# aaa,bbb
# aaa
# bbb
```

`.writerow()` には, リストのようなもの(イテラブル) を指定し
`.writerows()` の場合は, リストのリスト的なもの(row のイテラブル) を指定

質問の `writer.writerows(list_a)` あるいは `writer.writerow(li)` では, 目的とする出力には次元がひとつずつ足りない。

また, 文字列もイテラブルであり このため一文字ずつ扱われます

```py
for c in 'abcde':
    print(c)
a
b
c
d
e
```

以上のことから, `.writerows()` 使って1項目ずつ書き込むには次のようなデータ構造が必要になります

```py
    rows = [['一行目'],
            ['二行目'],
            ['三行目']]
    writer.writerows(rows)
```